# How is Turkish economy handling the pressure of so much defense purchase?

Tags: macroeconomics

[How did Turkey manage to create a springboard for its defense industry so fast?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/18946/17569)

1. [TFX program costs USD 10bn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TAI_TFX)
2. [S-400 purchase costs USD 2.5bn](http://www.israeldefense.co.il/en/node/30343)
3. [Turkey targets 30% hike in military spending next year](https://www.al-monitor.com/pulse/originals/2017/10/turkey-military-government-adopts-war-budget-for-2018.html)

How is Turkish economy handling the pressure of so much defense purchase?

Answer (score 2):

Turkey had an estimated military spending of [$14.8 billion](https://www.al-monitor.com/pulse/originals/2017/10/turkey-military-government-adopts-war-budget-for-2018.html) in 2016.

A 30% increase would be a $4.5 billion increase. That's 0.5% of GDP. Turkey's government budget deficit was [1.1%](https://tradingeconomics.com/turkey/government-budget) in 2016. All else equals, the budget deficit would rise to 1.6% with that kind of increase in spending. Either that or they cut spending elsewhere.